# Replace All Characters In A String With '*' Character

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I'v searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer, if i'm wrong please direct me to the post, otherwise here's my question:

I want to replace a string (ex. "password") to all '*' but it still has the number of chars that the string has in it, for example "password" has 8 chars so it would replace it like this "********" instead of password, or any other string(ex. "word" > "****", "string" > "******").

If anyone can help me out here that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean 'show as stars during input'? Or to transform some existing text to 'hide' the known password? Or to create a new string with the given number of stars, given a string of any length?

Comment: Already answered below, thanks though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
Function HideString(str As String) As String
    Return New String("*"c, str.Length)
End Function
```

This function creates a new string using the '*' character but with the same length as the input string.

You can use it like this:

```
Dim test As String = HideString("password")
```

Comment: Thanks worked beautifully, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Nit Picking :  `Return New String("*"c, Trim(str).Length)`, I suggest you yo use `TRIM()` to avoid trailing spaces.

Comment: @VivekS. Nit Picking, a password possibly could have a trailing space! maybe!

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex.replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx) approach :

```
RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("password", "[a-zA-Z]", "*")
```

You can create a function like below

```
 Private Function strReplace(ByVal str As String, ByVal char2replace As String)
     Dim lstr As String = Trim(str)
     str = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(lstr, "[a-zA-Z]", char2replace)
    'or you can use 
    'str = Regex.Replace(lstr, "[a-zA-Z]", char2replace)
    'but in this case you need to import System.Text.RegularExpressions
     Return lstr
 End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim str As String = " PassWORD "
str = strReplace(str, "*")
'Output : ********
Dim str As String = "password"
str = strReplace(str, "#")
'Output : ########
```